# Angular 2 rc1, Address line bug?

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm having some problems with the new routing in angular2 rc1, so I wanted to check out if the demo project has the same problems, and it appears so. Here is a link to a copy of the demo project. I haven't done any changes:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/G4nYQWgCuhP1bqDs3mye?p=preview
```

here's the routes:

```
@Routes([
  {path: '/crisis-center',  component: CrisisCenterComponent},
  {path: '/heroes',  component: HeroListComponent},
  {path: '/hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent},
])
```

when navigating to the default page, we are redirected to /crisis-center. Then when clicking for instance "Dragon Burninng Cities" we are redirected to /crisis-center/1. So far so good. But if I enter the direct link to /crisis-center/1 in the address bar of Chrome, somehow the relative paths are messed up, and Chrome wants to load the app folder below crisis-center:

[image]

The same problem happens with /hero/1

When clicking around and trying to set different addresses directly, all sorts of errors occurs, probably related to this problem.

If anyone has a workaround it would be greatly appreciated.